# How do you add a child node to a parent in an adjacency list in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was looking at the example below.  My program is setup similar but without the backref.  I want a one-to-many relationship.  Children need not know their parents.  I am just a but confused as the line "node = TreeNode('rootnode')", wouldn't that be ran everytime the program is executed and possibly create duplicates?

How do you add a subnode without the parent backref?

I see for example the following

```
node = TreeNode('rootnode')
TreeNode('node1', parent=node)
```

node1 is created with name 'node1' and it's parent is passed alone.  parent is defined in the children relationship as

```
backref("parent", remote_side=id)
```

I don't much need children to know parents, just parents knowing children.  How do you create the relationship so parents know children?

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/adjacency_list/adjacency_list.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rootnode = TreeNode('rootnode')
# assign "children" attribute straight away:
node1 = TreeNode('node1', 
    children=[TreeNode('node1.child1'), TreeNode('node1.child2')]
    )
# or just manipulate as any regular list
rootnode.children.append(node1)
```

---

I the example you link to `parent` already knows `children` by the fact that the `relationship` children is defined:

```
children = relationship("TreeNode", # NOTE: now each TreeNode has "children"
                    # ...
                    backref=backref("parent", remote_side=id), # this line allows children to link to "parent"
                    # ...
                )
```

Therefore

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Worked great,